# Javascript target one input in function

Tags: javascript

JavaScript newbie, I have a little misunderstanding of this concept. Hope someone can help me out. I built a keyboard that needs to pass it's characters to a selected input field. This works without a problem when I target the first input field. If for example there are 3 inputs: name, email, password.. I can target any of them singularly and input the value of the keys. However if I then select a second input field (email for example).. the key characters add to now email input field and also the input first selected, Same if I then choose the password input.. the value will be added to all three inputs.

When I pass the input to the keyToInput function it is found. However when I pass the field and call a console log on it after the keyValue.foreEach() function, all three inputs are selected.

Obviously I am having problems with the forEach() function.. but I've tried many things but just not sure how to continue further.

Hope this makes sense! thanks for any explanation.

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" class="form-control" name="name"
                                        required>
                                       
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email_address" class="form-control"
                                        name="email" required>
                                       
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control"
                                        name="password" required maxlength="5">
```

```html
{{--KEYBOARD KEYPAD--}}
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade animate" id="keyPadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="keyPadModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content animate-bottom">
            <div class="modal-body keyPadModal">
                <div class="keypad-text">
                    <div id="keypad-keys">
                        {{--KeyPad WINDOW 1 UPPERCASE--}}
                        <div id="key-win-uppercase" class="key-win">
                            <div class="key-line key-line-1">
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="Q">Q</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="W">W</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="E">E</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="R">R</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="T">T</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="Y">Y</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="U">U</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="I">I</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="O">O</div>
                                <div class="keypad-text-key key-put" data-val="P">P</div>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```js
const inputField = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const keyValue = document.querySelectorAll(".key-put");
```

```js
function keyToInput(field) {
    keyValue.forEach(function (el) {
        el.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (e.target.getAttribute("data-val")) {
                flashKey(e.target);
                const inp = el.getAttribute("data-val");
                console.log(inp);
                console.log(field);
                //field.value = field.value + inp;
            } else {
                console.log("no value");
            }
        });
    });
}

inputField.forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener("click", function (element) {
        $("#keyPadModal").modal("show");
        keyToInput(element.target);
    });
});
```

Comment: give your html code

Comment: Added not the full the keyboard obviously. Hope its enough to give you an idea

Comment: Here's a working example, basically you need to keep track of which field is currently selected: https://jsfiddle.net/nhej3vy9/1/

Comment: what should be done with all the div tags which contains Q,W,E ....etc.

Comment: i guess , you want all keyboard characters and onclicking any keyboard character it will fillup in the selected input field not other input fields . am i right ?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct. I am working with the example from Jared Farrish.. If you have another solution I would really be thankful. It's nice to see how it can be done in more than one way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**he is a better coder who can do any complex code in a very clean and easy syntax which anyone can understand easily as their own. you can add css yourself. any doubt you can ask me in comment section below .**

```js
let val1=""
let val2=""
let val3=""
let focusedID=""
let focused=(id)=>{
    focusedID=id
}
let show=(id)=>{
    if(focusedID=="name"){
        val1+=id
        document.getElementById(focusedID).value=val1
    }
    if(focusedID=="email_address"){
        val2+=id
        document.getElementById(focusedID).value=val2
    }
    if(focusedID=="password"){
        val3+=id
        document.getElementById(focusedID).value=val3
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="focused(id)" placeholder="Name" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" required />
<input type="text" onfocus="focused(id)" placeholder="Email" id="email_address" class="form-control" name="email" required/>
<input type="password" onfocus="focused(id)" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" required/>
<div>
    <button id="A" onclick="show(id)">A</button>
    <button id="B" onclick="show(id)">B</button>
    <button id="C" onclick="show(id)">C</button>
    <button id="D" onclick="show(id)">D</button>
    <button id="E" onclick="show(id)">E</button>
    <button id="F" onclick="show(id)">F</button>
    <button id="G" onclick="show(id)">G</button>
    <button id="H" onclick="show(id)">H</button>
    <button id="I" onclick="show(id)">I</button>
    <button id="J" onclick="show(id)">J</button>
    <button id="K" onclick="show(id)">K</button>
    <button id="L" onclick="show(id)">L</button>
    <button id="M" onclick="show(id)">M</button>
    <button id="N" onclick="show(id)">N</button>
    <button id="O" onclick="show(id)">O</button>
    <button id="P" onclick="show(id)">P</button>
    <button id="Q" onclick="show(id)">Q</button>
    <button id="R" onclick="show(id)">R</button>
    <button id="S" onclick="show(id)">S</button>
    <button id="T" onclick="show(id)">T</button>
    <button id="U" onclick="show(id)">U</button>
    <button id="V" onclick="show(id)">V</button>
    <button id="W" onclick="show(id)">W</button>
    <button id="X" onclick="show(id)">X</button>
    <button id="Y" onclick="show(id)">Y</button>
    <button id="Z" onclick="show(id)">Z</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution! thank you very much.. Just what in needed it to do.